# angularjs routing not work for me

Tags: angularjs-routing

Please help me.

[Here is my code](http://plnkr.co/n2opykqNhceF6RhwSqbF).

**Javascript:**

```
        var myMailMod = angular.module('myMail', []);

    function configView($routeProvider)
    {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'list.html',
            controller: 'ListController'
        }).
        when('/view/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'details.html',
            controller: 'DetailsController'
        }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }

    myMailMod.config(configView);

    var messages = [
        {
            id:0, sender: 'mahshad', date:'14/8/2014',
            recipients: ['missprogrammer@yahoo.com', 'test@gmail.com'],
            subject: 'salam', text: 'salam shaghaliiiiii khobi? :x'
        },
        {
            id:1, sender: 'enayat', date:'16/8/2014',
            recipients: ['aryanpour1990@gmail.com'],
            subject: 'salam', text: 'khobam to khobi? che khabar?!'
        },
        {
            id:2, sender: 'nooshin', date:'18/8/2014',
            recipients: ['nooshin@yahoo.com'],
            subject: 'salam', text: 'salam chetoriah? hahaha :)'
        }
    ];

    myMailMod.controller('ListController', function($scope)
    {
        $scope.messages = messages;
    });

    myMailMod.controller('DetailsController', function($scope, $routeParams)
    {
        $scope.message = messages[$routeParams.id];
    });
```

**HTML(1):**

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.21"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>myMail app</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**HTML(2):**

```
<div>sender: {{messages.sender}}</div>
<div>date: {{messages.date}}</div>
<div>from: <span ng-repeat="recipient in messages.recipients">{{recipient}}</span></div>
<div>subject: {{messages.subject}}</div>
<div>{{messages.text}}</div>
```

**HTML(3):**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Sender</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="message in messages">
        <td>{{message.sender}}</td>
        <td><a ng-href="#/view/{{messages.id}}">{{message.subject}}</a></td>
        <td>{{message.date}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What should i do?

Comment: have you included angular-route.js ?

Comment: oh! thanks, solved! in firefox it works, but in chrome not works! :)

Comment: may be that was file accessibility issue for chrome.